# how to use multiple FormArray in angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have such form. And I want to create dynamic multiple FormArray when I change Category dropdown. These FormArrays are inside *ngFor in html. How Can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

[image]

I have already seen this
https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/#importing-formarray

and it works. But I can't use for multiple.

Comment: what is the issue can you show your code

Comment: I just wrote code as this 

https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/#importing-formarray

but I can't understand how to use it for multiple FormArray.

Comment: can you show your code